# Generalizing the fix-point properties to multi-dimensional functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, graphing-functions, recreational-mathematics

$x,y,z\in\mathbb R^3.$ $c:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$. $a,b$ are constants.

Function $f(x,y,z)$ satisfies that $\forall z_1,z_2\in\mathbb R$, we have
$$\{(x,y)||f(x,y,z_1)=f(x,y,z_2)\}=\{(x,y)||ax+by=c(z_1,z_2)\},$$

which intuitively means, for any $z_1,z_2$, the graph of $(x,y)$ is a line.

Given the information, what is a good decomposition for $f$?

---

By "decomposition", I mean to find a function form $F$, such that

$$f(x,y,z)=F(f_1(x),f_2(y),f_3(z),f_4(x,y),f_5(y,z),f_6(x,z)).$$

For example, one form that works is $f(x,y,z)=g(ax+by,z)$. But it is too strong and not necessary for our property.

Of course, you can assume the monotonicity of each $f_i$ or $F$, if needed. Each $f_i$ can remain unknown (and they might have to).

---

To be clearer, one could consider a two-dimensional case, $f(x,y)$. Define $g(x)=f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)+x$. Our property is equivalent of saying that the fix point of $g(x)$ is globally unique. We are generalizing the uniqueness of fix-point to multiple dimensions.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174400/sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-the-global-uniqueness-of-fix-points?noredirect=1#comment6535263_3174400) is a Related Question

Comment: I can not fully wrap my head around the concept. But it seems strange to me that functions $f_1, \dots , f_6$ appear? If there is a solution $F$, then we can create another solution $\tilde{F}(x,y,z)=F(f_1(x), \dots , f_6(x,z))$. Do the $f_i$'s have additional properties? What am I missing?

Comment: In the given example $f(x,y,z)=g(ax+by,z)$, we have $F=g$, $f_1=f_2=f_5=f_6=0$, $f_3(z)=z$, $f_4(x,y)=ax+by$. Is it now clearer?