# Sufficient and necessary condition for the global uniqueness of fix-points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-060-01/S0002-9939-1976-0423137-6/S0002-9939-1976-0423137-6.pdf

This paper gives a sufficient condition for the uniqueness of SCHAUDER fix point. I wonder if there are any sufficient and necessary results, whether published or not, for the uniqueness of Brouwer, Banach, or Schauder fix point.

Many thanks!

[Here is a related question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174251/generalizing-the-fix-point-properties-to-multi-dimensional-functions)

Comment: Regarding the Banach fixed point theorem: a fixed point is *always* unique.  Another (fairly) simple result: if $(K,d)$ is a compact metric space and $f\colon K\to K$ has the property that $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ for any $x,y\in K$ such that $x\ne y$ then $f$ has a unique fixed point in $K$.

Comment: @user539887 you are right! Banach assumes the map to be contracting, and of course, the fix-point is unique. The condition of "contracting" is sufficient but not necessary to have a unique fixed point.